# Pandas dataframe values not changing outside of function

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe inside a for loop where I change a value in pandas dataframe like this:

```
df[item].ix[(e1,e2)] = 1
```

However when I access the df, the values are still unchanged. Do you know where exactly am I going wrong?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `.ix`, it's been deprecated. But I suspect the problem is that `df[item]` is returning a copy, which you then update and immediately discard. so just try `df.loc[item, (e1, e2)] = 1`

Comment: Elisha512, feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem or to let me know what else I can do to help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using chained indexing, which usually causes problems.  In your code, `df[item]` returns a series, and then `.ix[(e1,e2)] = 1` modifies that series, leaving the original dataframe untouched.  You need to modify the original dataframe instead, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': [5, 6, 1, 2, 3],
                   'colB': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

print df
df.ix[[1, 2], 'colA'] = 111
print df
```

That code sets rows 1 and 2 of colA to 111, which I believe is the kind of thing you were looking to do.  1 and 2 could be replaced with variables of course.

```
   colA colB
0     5    a
1     6    b
2     1    c
3     2    d
4     3    e

   colA colB
0     5    a
1   111    b
2   111    c
3     2    d
4     3    e
```

For more information on chained indexing, see the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

**Side note:** you may also want to rethink your code in general since you mentioned modifying a dataframe in a loop.  When using pandas, you usually can and should avoid looping and leverage set-based operations instead.  It takes some getting used to, but it's the way to unlock the full power of the library.